# Read-Only Memory vs Heap Memory in Memory Usage in C

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Assume we have a Struct NODE with

```
typedef struct tNODE {
    struct tNODE* parent;
    char* inner_text;
}NODE;
```

Here we have a Read-Only Memory usage of initialization

```
NODE* temp = new_node(parent);
temp->inner_text = "something";
```

Vs.
Heap Memory usage of initialization

```
NODE* temp = new_node(parent);
temp->inner_text = strdup("something");
```

So what I am doing in my program is that, I am parsing through an XML file(the original node struct has more components).

My question is that if I am using read-only memory I have noticed from Valgrind that the total Heap usage is a bit lower than when I am using Heap Allocation.

Is that always true ? why is that ? I work with large files(>3GB), should I take that into consideration ?

Comment: Read only program memory is not for free. It consumes heap during program load.

Comment: Yes but why does it require less Heap Usage ?

Comment: If string is not in heap, it doesn't use heap. That seems rather obvious, so what exactly is your confusion, can you clarify?

Comment: Version with strdup() still use ro program memory to store the string literal but also use this literal to consume normal heap via strdup()

Answer (score 1):

In your "Heap Memory usage" example ...

> ```
> NODE* temp = new_node(parent);
> temp->inner_text = strdup("something");
> ```

... you require at least double the storage for the string, because you actually have *two*.  `strdup()` will dynamically allocate memory for a copy of the contents of the string literal, but you still have the string literal too (else, what do you think `strdup()` could copy *from*?).

This is not a question of string literal vs. not.  I anticipate that you would observe similar memory usage (in both examples) if you replaced the string literal with an explicit, modifiable array such as this:

```
char something[] = {'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
```

If the underlying question is about how to initialize modifiable arrays, then you would probably find this more convenient:

```
char something[] = "something";
```

If that appears at file scope, then there is a fair chance that no additional storage is consumed beyond that for your writable array.

Answer (score 1):

The string `"something"` is (obviously) known at compile time, right?

So, instead of assigning a string literal, introduce a global variable like `const char *something = "something";` and assign that to the field of the node.

Even if you assign the (literal) same string, the compiler will probably figure this out and will take care of the above step.

At least GCC (12.2.0) does that on my system, test it out:

```
struct foo { char *value; };

void processFoo(struct foo *bar)
{
    printf("%p\n", bar->value);
}

int main()
{
    struct foo f1 = { .value = "hello" };
    processFoo(&f1);

    struct foo f2 = { .value = "hello" };
    processFoo(&f2);

    printf("\n");

    for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
        struct foo *bar = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
        bar->value = "hello";
        processFoo(bar);
        free(bar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0x55b6389f4008
0x55b6389f4008

0x55b6389f4008
0x55b6389f4008
0x55b6389f4008
```

---

As a reply to the comment below:

Considering the fact, that a `strdup` will (unnecessarily) increase the heap usage by creating a copy of an persistent object (which has been already pointed out by the users John Bollinger and ulix), there will be no additional increase in memory usage if you assign a well known (since it's hard coded it has to be) string literal, let's say 10 quadrillion times.

Comment: I'm not following how this is different from the OP's "Read-only memory" example, especially (though this is unclear) if the objective is to use modifiable strings.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand here is that there are *TWO* objects here -- there's a `NODE` object (containing two pointers) and a string object (`char[10]` array containing the string, including a NUL terminator).

In both cases, the `NODE` object is allocated on the heap.  In the first case, the string is allocated in read-only memory, while in the second case, the string is allocated on the heap.  The `strdup` allocates this string on the heap, and there may also be a string in read-only memory for strdup to copy, or that may be eliminated by the optimizer.